# How to run EJB scheduler in parallel

Tags: java, ejb, scheduler

I am trying to run the poll,poll1,poll2 methods to run independently, right now if poll() is running and the processing time is taking more than 10 sec, other methods are waiting for poll() to complete its processing. I kept a break point at poll() sys out and other method sys out are not executing.
How to solve this ? Below is the code base.

Also I tried with adding

```
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)
@Lock(LockType.READ)
```

but found no change in the behaviour.

```
@Singleton
public class SchedulerA {

    @Schedule(second = "*/10", minute = "*", hour = "*", persistent = false)
    public void poll() {
        System.out.println("SchedulerA:: poll()");
    }

    @Schedule(second = "*/10", minute = "*", hour = "*", persistent = false)
    public void poll1() {
        System.out.println("SchedulerA:: poll()1");

    }

    @Schedule(second = "*/10", minute = "*", hour = "*", persistent = false)
    public void poll2() {
        System.out.println("SchedulerA:: poll()2");

    }

}
```

I am expecting if poll() is running (put a break point /or add a for loop which take more than 10 sec) output show 
SchedulerA:: poll()1
SchedulerA:: poll()2
after 10 sec again
SchedulerA:: poll()1
SchedulerA:: poll()2

Comment: I also tried with spiting the methods in individual classes, i.e poll() in ScheduleA, poll1() in SchedulerB and poll2() in SchedulerC class but got the same result. If poll() is processing other thread are in wait.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some workaround is to use [ManagedScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedScheduledExecutorService.html).
Use it by injecting like this:

```
@Resource
private ManagedScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;
```

and schedule above tasks in @PostConstruct to be executed with fixed delay e.g.

```
scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(this::poll, 1, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

etc.